# Using Dependency Injection to Initialize values via Constructors

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, constructor

I have a Class `UserService` that implements interface `IUserService`.

The `UserService` class has constructor to initialize values to it's parameters.

I am using the `UserService` in another class via DI.

How to initialize the values for UserService object.

```
public class OfferService : IOfferService
{
    private IUserService _userService;
    private ISomeOtherService _someotherService;

    public OfferService(IUserService userService, ISomeOtherService someotherService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
        _someotherService = someotherService;
    }

    public bool SomeMethod()
    {
        string key = _someotherService.GetKey();
        string value = _someotherService.GetValue();

        //Calling parameterized constructor of UserService

        var user = new UserService(key,value);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to use the Interface reference `_userService` to initialize values via constructor.

Comment: You cannot define a constructor in an interface. You could include setters to inject data. But besides that, `_userService` is being injected into `OfferService`, suggesting that the user service has already been initialized via constructor. Could you elaborate on what you want?

Comment: @ps_dev the confusion is that if you are already injecting `IUserService` into `OfferService` then why are you trying to initialize it within your class?

Comment: The question is unclear.

Comment: @ps_dev: I was pointing to when you have access to those two values. If you are extracting them from request or those are somewhere in the database or somewhere else. Where do you get them from?

Comment: @ps_dev: Why not passing `ISomeOtherService` into constructor of `UserService` same way how you pass `IUserService` into `OfferService`?

Comment: @dropoutcoder This is how the code actually is. I just want to know how to use the parameterized constructor in UserService.cs.

Comment: @ps_dev what platform is this for? This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: We need to see a [mcve]. Please also show us how `IUserService` is registered with your IoC container.

Comment: `_userService to initialize values via constructor.` The direct answer to that question is **No**. I mean _theoretically_ you could via Reflection, but it would be worse than your existing code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to handle this is by injecting a factory instead of an instance. That will allow you to supply the parameters at runtime.

Simple factory example:

```
public interface IUserServiceFactory
{
    IUserService GetUserService(string key, string val);
}

public class UserServiceFactory : IUserServiceFactory
{
    public IUserService GetUserService(string key, string val)
    {
        return new UserService(key, val);
    }
}
```

How to use it:

```
public class OfferService : IOfferService
{
    private IUserServiceFactory _userServiceFactory;
    private ISomeOtherService _someotherService;

    public OfferService(IUserServiceFactory userServiceFactory, ISomeOtherService someotherService)
    {
        _userServiceFactory = userServiceFactory;
        _someotherService = someotherService;
    }

    public bool SomeMethod()
    {
        string key = _someotherService.GetKey();
        string val = _someotherService.GetValue();

        var user = _userServiceFactory.GetUserService(key, val);

        return false;
    }
}
```

See my [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0MHDo4)

Comment: Personally I'd not recommend this for *the case shown in this post* as making UserService depending on OtherService as shown in Nkosi answer makes more sense ... Would be perfectly fine if class would need to create multiple "user" objects for example.

Comment: I agree, sometimes. It depends on which class has the responsibility of coordinating the two services.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to use the Interface reference `_userService` to initialize values via constructor.

Short answer: **NO**

If you want to get around having to new up anything manually then you need to design in such a way that your classes explicitly define their dependencies and avoid implementation details.

For example

```
public class OfferService : IOfferService {
    private readonly IUserService userService;

    public OfferService(IUserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;            
    }

    public bool SomeMethod() {

        //...use userService

    }
} 


public class UserService : IUserService {

    public UserService(ISomeOtherService someotherService)
        string key = someotherService.GetKey();
        string value = someotherService.GetValue();

        //...
    }

    //...
}
```

And ensure that everything is properly registered with the IoC container it the composition root.

I would also suggest reviewing

[Dependency Injection Code Smell: Injecting runtime data into components](https://blogs.cuttingedge.it/steven/posts/2015/code-smell-injecting-runtime-data-into-components/)

to get another perspective about how `UserService` could be refactored to avoid the current  issue.